# Why have my site stopped working at azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2019

When loggin into my site at azure I get an error

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    GetTogetherWeb2.Models.AdminDAL.IsAdmin(Int32 user_id) in
>   C:\TEMP\flow3_2_1\flow3_2_1\Models\AdminDAL.cs:148
>   [image]
>   The error is not when I run it on localhost. All firewalls are open, all database servers works as they should.

The error turned up 1 week ago, and I have not gotten any way near a solution. I have had the webpage on Azure for 2 years with no problems deploying the project.

We are deploying on a regular basis, and it came with a deployment. However, when we rolled back the deployments to an older version, the same error was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put some logs to check the value of your object in the `AdminDAL.cs` line `148`
you have `NullReferenceException` The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception?view=netcore-3.1